# accessing a method in .jar file from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to access a method in an api say xyz-api.jar located in a server. inside my javascript function, how should i proceed?

We cannot use servlets here as there is no access to the server. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Applets and RMI to interact with server and call the applet methods in javascript !

Here's a small example to go with

http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4U8FM6

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the java object method from javascript code without a servlet/jsp or other server-side codes.